# SQLite: Retrieve record by passing two values

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one table "TABLE_QUESTION". I need to fetch record by passing **exam_id** and **question_Id**. I write one query to fetch record from table but it shows exception `"SQLite Exception near question_id"`.

Here is my query for your reference..

```
 String selectQuery=("select * from question where exam_id ='" + examId + " and question_id ='" + questionId +"'" );
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed one single quote after `examId + "` must be  `examId + " '`

```
String selectQuery=("select * from question where exam_id ='" + examId + "' and question_id ='" + questionId +"'" );
```

Comment: :i ALWAYS GET CONFUSE with dis single and double quote,Do u have any reference to make it clear

Comment: can refer this tips http://www.techtamasha.com/escape-single-quotes-and-wild-cards-_-in-ms-sql/20